# Mass updating mysql rows: better performance to exclude those already having the value?

Tags: mysql

Given the following query:

```
UPDATE large_table SET column_b='' WHERE column_timestamp < 1434365125;
```

The timestamp is a moving target and will change for each day.

On subsequent runs, will the query benefit from having "AND column_b != ''" added to the where clause or is mysql smart enough to sort of add that automatically in a way in the background? Is this documented somewhere?

And as an aside; would it be better performance wise to set it to NULL instead of a blank string or doesn't that matter? Tables are InnoDB.

Comment: " or is mysql smart enough to sort of add that automatically in a way in the background". No, it isn't smart enough. What criteria you want to specify in the query is entirely up to you. SQL will execute whatever you tell it - and it has no idea _why_ you want to do it. But if that clause results in writing less rows then it's probably a good idea. Usually though the only way to truly measure performance is to test it. It's not a big change to test...so go ahead. Indexing could play a part as well depending which columns are indexed.

Comment: Is `column_b` indexed? Writing is more expensive than reading, especially if there is an index on that field. So yes performance will benefit.

Comment: And NULL would not really be better performance-wise AFAIK but arguably it's more semantically correct to represent "no value" - an empty string is not the absence of a value, it's simply a string with no characters in it, but it's still a value of sorts.

Comment: MySQL won't actually do the update if a given record already has `b` set to empty string.  What the index does would also depend on how many rows are not empty string each day.

Answer (score 1):

Is `column_b` indexed? Writing is more expensive than reading, especially if there is an index on that field. So yes performance will benefit.

> ...is mysql smart enough to sort of add that automatically in a way...

It would not be smart if MySQL would do that. The big problem is the binary log. If MySQL would decide on its own to skip data, you would get into trouble in some point in time. The replication slaves would get out of sync and the shards (=partitioned tables) would be inconsistent at some point in time.

MySQL is smart enough to optimize your queries but that is concerning index, query cache, execution path, ... it does not in any way change the intent of your query, concerning the data itself, there is no optimization.

Best practice is to use the `EXPLAIN` statement before your query and reduce the amount of rows and fields MySQL has to investigate.

Another optimization would be to exclude rows already changed in the far past. Assume your query runs once a day, you can add a lower boundary:

```
WHERE column_timestamp < [today] AND column_timestamp > [today - 2 days]
```